# Horizontal scroll bar in Opera (11.0)

Tags: html, css, browser, scrollbar, opera

Currently developing this site and I can't pin point as to why there is a horizontal scroll bar and a huge amount of white space added in opera.

http://thefinishedbox.com/ - If you have Opera browser you (should) see what I mean.

Theres no additional space added in other browsers.

Anyone know why this is?

P.S this css file is designed for higher resolutions so you will automatically see a scrollbar on 1024px width resolution monitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site seems to perform ok in Opera (OSX) however I am replicating the issue with the x scrollbar I wonder could it be to do with the min-width and width tags? to rectify you could hide the x overflow?

Comment: Hasn't worked no, ive tried overflow for .content not sure what else i would apply that to.

Comment: Solution was to put `overflow:hidden` on the `header` tag... I'll give you the green tick since you have like no points lol.

Comment: Cheers Daryl I appreciate it buddy best of british! ;)